# Retrieve certain string from a list of word for flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

I have this list of word

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 99_99_9) AppleWebKit/999.99 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/99.9.9999.999 Safari/999.99
```

How do i get the word 'Mac OS X'

Answer (score 1):

Use [indexOf](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.12.4/dart-core/String/indexOf.html) with combination of [substring](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.12.4/dart-core/String/substring.html).